# Flutter bloc_pattern returning NoSuchMethodError

Tags: flutter, dart, bloc

I am building my first Flutter app, and foolishly enough, I started off with complex structures such as the MVVM, I don't know very much about it but have tried.

Here is my folder structure:

```
lib
---models
------videos.dart
---repos
------videos.dart
---viewmodels
------videos.dart
main.dart (I know)
```

In my `main.dart` file, I am using StreamBuilder to fetch the lisit of videos, here's the code:

```
class Home extends StatelessWidget {
  VideosBloc videosBloc = BlocProvider.getBloc<VideosBloc>();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        Expanded(
          flex: 1,
          child: CustomAppBar(),
        ),
        Expanded(
          flex: 9,
          child: Container(
            color: Theme.of(context).primaryColorDark,
            child: StreamBuilder(
              stream: videosBloc.videosStream,
              builder: (context, snapshot) {
                List<Video> videos = snapshot != null ? snapshot.data : [];
                return ListView(
                  children: videos.map((video) {
                    return VideoContainer(video);
                  }).toList(),
                );
              },
            ),
          ),
        )
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

There there is this bloc file:

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:bloc_pattern/bloc_pattern.dart';
import 'package:peeke_vines/models/videos.dart';
import 'package:peeke_vines/repositories/videos.dart';
import 'package:rxdart/rxdart.dart';

class VideosBloc extends BlocBase {
  VideosBloc();

  //Stream that receives a number and changes the count;
  var _videosController =
      BehaviorSubject<List<Video>>.seeded(VideosRepo().getVideos());

  //output
  Stream<List<Video>> get videosStream => _videosController.stream;
  //input
  Sink<List<Video>> get videosSink => _videosController.sink;

  //dispose will be called automatically by closing its streams
  @override
  void dispose() {
    _videosController.close();
    super.dispose();
  }
}
```

And this bloc gets this data from a repository

```
import 'package:peeke_vines/models/videos.dart';

class VideosRepo {
  VideosRepo();

  List<Video> videos = VideoModel().fetchVideos();

  List<Video> getVideos() {
    return [];
  }
}
```

And this repository currently just gets the data from a model, but later I'll implement a web service to fetch the data from:

```
import 'package:meta/meta.dart';

class VideoModel {
  List<Video> fetchVideos() {
    return [
      Video(
          video: 'assets/videos/main.wmv',
          title: 'Peeke Vines Video Title',
          date: '2 Days ago',
          thumbnail: 'assets/thumbnails/1.jpg',
          duration: 13.5),
      Video(
          video: 'assets/videos/main.wmv',
          title: 'Peeke Vines Video Title',
          date: '2 Days ago',
          thumbnail: 'assets/thumbnails/2.jpg',
          duration: 13.5),
      Video(
          video: 'assets/videos/main.wmv',
          title: 'Peeke Vines Video Title',
          date: '2 Days ago',
          thumbnail: 'assets/thumbnails/1.jpg',
          duration: 13.5)
    ];
  }
}

class Video {
  String video, title, date, thumbnail;
  double duration;

  Video(
      {@required this.video,
      @required this.title,
      @required this.date,
      @required this.thumbnail,
      @required this.duration});
}
```

Now, whenever I import the bloc in the main.dart file using this line:

```
VideosBloc videosBloc = BlocProvider.getBloc<VideosBloc>();
```

I get this error:

```
I/flutter ( 4338): ══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY WIDGETS LIBRARY ╞═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
I/flutter ( 4338): The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown building MyApp(dirty):
I/flutter ( 4338): Class 'NoSuchMethodError' has no instance getter 'message'.
I/flutter ( 4338): Receiver: Instance of 'NoSuchMethodError'
I/flutter ( 4338): Tried calling: message
I/flutter ( 4338):
I/flutter ( 4338): When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
I/flutter ( 4338): #0      Object.noSuchMethod (dart:core-patch/object_patch.dart:50:5)
I/flutter ( 4338): #1      BlocProvider.getBloc (package:bloc_pattern/src/bloc_provider.dart:47:12)
I/flutter ( 4338): #2      new Home (package:peeke_vines/main.dart:35:40)
I/flutter ( 4338): #3      MyApp.build (package:peeke_vines/main.dart:21:20)
I/flutter ( 4338): #4      StatelessElement.build (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3974:28)
I/flutter ( 4338): #5      ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3924:15)
I/flutter ( 4338): #6      Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3721:5)
I/flutter ( 4338): #7      ComponentElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3907:5)
I/flutter ( 4338): #8      ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3902:5)
I/flutter ( 4338): #9      Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3084:14)
I/flutter ( 4338): #10     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2887:12)
I/flutter ( 4338): #11     RenderObjectToWidgetElement._rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:939:16)
I/flutter ( 4338): #12     RenderObjectToWidgetElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:910:5)
I/flutter ( 4338): #13     RenderObjectToWidgetAdapter.attachToRenderTree.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:856:17)
I/flutter ( 4338): #14     BuildOwner.buildScope (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2320:19)
I/flutter ( 4338): #15     RenderObjectToWidgetAdapter.attachToRenderTree (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:855:13)
```

Can you tell me why this error is coming?

Comment: Did you register `VideosBloc ` on top of MaterialApp?

Comment: @Martyns Can you please elaborate, how can I do that, I am very very new to this but understand a few things.

Comment: I mean the part in the docs that says "Now add the BlocProvider widget before MaterialApp" https://pub.dev/packages/bloc_pattern  I recommend you looking at the bloc pattern without the need of a pub package, you will understand the core concept better. But basically you cannot get a VideosBloc if it is not "provided" somewhere in the widget tree.

Comment: Also I recommend you to check out https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/InheritedWidget-class.html which is what Bloc is built on top of. Inherited widgets is what Flutter uses to provide, for instance, the Theme to all your widgets. As you see is the same thing as providing Blocs

Comment: @Martyns Yeah about that, I am using the BlocProvider as my root widget and in it's `blocs` list, I am injecting VideosBloc

Comment: Oh I think the issue could be trying to get the Bloc outside the build method. Try to get it at the start of the build method.

Comment: Great to hear that it worked!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you are trying to get the Bloc outside of the build method. 
Try to get it at the start of the build method.